# If $a_k\ge 0$ for all $k$ show that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^na_k\le b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Given that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow1^-} \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k = b \in\mathbb{R}$ for $|x|<1$. If $a_k\ge 0$ for all $k$ show that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^na_k\le b$.

This is just a step in another proof that I am working on. If I can show this my proof is complete.

The trouble I am having is that I'm not sure I believe it. $x$ could be negative so couldn't $\sum\limits_{k=0}^na_k > b$? I know this can't be as it is given as fact, but I fail to see why?

Comment: It doesn't matter if $x$ can be negative, because you only check $x$ in a neighbourhood of 1 (to the left) when you are dealing with $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow1^-} \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k = b \in\mathbb{R}$ , so it could say as well  " ...for $x \in (1-\epsilon , 1)$ "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is true because, in a neighbourhood of 1 $(1-\epsilon , 1) $ 
you have that $\ a_k\ x^k \geq 0 \ \  \forall k$ so you can interchange the limits (The infinite sum is a limit),so:

$$b = \lim\limits_{N\rightarrow +\infty} \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow1^-} \sum\limits_{k=0}^N a_kx^k =\lim\limits_{N\rightarrow +\infty}  \sum\limits_{k=0}^N a_k \geq \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k \ \ \forall \ n  $$

Answer (score 2):

Wlog we may assume that $x > 0$. For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we get

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k x^{k} \leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k x^{k}$$ by assumption.
Taking the limit of $x \to 1$ in this inequality shows the claim.